# Why would this query be returning null?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am working on setting up database storage for a game project I am working on for school, and am at the very beginning of doing so.  I am using MongoDB at the suggestion of our sponsor.  I have successfully implemented inserting a list of names with individual indices, but I cannot get it to return them.  The code I am using is as follows.

```
public string getName(int id) {
        var query = Query.EQ("_index", id);
        if (Names.FindOne(query) != null) return (Names.FindOne(query)).FirstName;
        else return "Error";
    }
```

I have now determined the problem is that the objects aren't being saved.  My code for doing so is

```
public void storeName(string name, int number) {
        Name Insert = new Name{FirstName = name, index = number};
        var query = Query.EQ("_FirstName", name);
        if (Names.FindOne(query) == null) { Names.Save<Name>(Insert); Console.WriteLine(Insert.index+" "+Insert.FirstName); }
        else {Console.WriteLine("Bork"); }
    }
```

And the Name object is automapped.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.  The index and FirstName fields needed to not have the underscores.